# Somebody have a responsive CSS template for Emails (newsletters)?

Tags: css, cross-platform, newsletter, responsive-design, email-client

I'm designing an HTML newsletter that is supposed to load nicely including on mobile devices.
I found these links to sites that show blank templates:

- http://www.emailology.org/
- http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/#f2

But with both I didn't succeed in showing responsive design on my mobile Android 2.3.3
Does someone have a live example for such responsive email, so I can learn from it?
I tried to look for one on the web but couldn't find one...

Comment: i recently coded responsive email templates at mojo themes
http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/shopmail-product-offer-responsive-email-template/

Answer (score 1):

Reading up on responsive HTML emails my self, I stumbled upon your question. Even though a bit late, I though I'd take the time to share what I've found so far.

I've found a couple of good resources to read, both provided by email newsletter web services.

1. Campaign Monitor provide a [pretty extensive guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/) on how to design responsive HTML emails. It discusses different approaches to take, things to think about and shows a few handy "hacks". In the guide, they also reference a few downloadable examples of responsive emails that you can use as a starting ground, and build your own email upon.
2. MailChimp also has a guide on [email for mobile devices](http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/email-on-mobile-devices/). It has a broader focus and discuss everything from statistics to user behavior and best practices, but it also has a section on various design approaches.

To get live examples to learn from, I suggest you sign up for newsletters by some of the major companies, that has spent time on developing their newsletters. I'm not going to market any company in particular, but I know that both above referenced guides mention a few companies that they think have great HTML newsletters, that could be worth having a look at.

Answer (score 0):

HTML emails are a different beast all together. There are a couple of websites dedicated to having HTML clients support standard markup, but that day is not anywhere close to becoming a reality. I doubt many email clients (if any) support the media queries needed for responsive CSS to work. My suggestion would be to make an HTML email template that is adaptable enough to work at a mobile resolution and still look good in an normal desktop resolution. Maybe some liquid widths.

For help with which clients support what and how well the support HTML / CSS features, check these two links out.

- [Email Standards Projects](http://www.email-standards.org/)
- [Campaign Monitor Email CSS Support](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: you didn't add any helpful information... if you have any evidence that responsive newsletter can't be done, you'll need to explain the two site's above which I gave the links to.

Comment: From one of your sites it states "Media queries will not work for mobile versions of Gmail." And I'd assume there's all sorts of issues in all the different mobile clients. I guess what I was trying to say is that writing templated emails isn't an exact science and I don't think there's a one solution fits all plug your html in and press send. I linked what I did to help you figure out what is supported in email clients and what isn't. I'll take a look at those templates and see if I can get some working examples.

Comment: yes, the issue is that those sites gave Allegedly dummy-proof templates, and it didn't worked for me, some i figured i might be missing something here...

Answer (score 0):

I have a superb solution for this issue. Solution is that - you can opt to create HTML email newsletter using fluid technique. I mean that you should build it in percentages - so that all the devices out there can fit your email.

I have a tutorial on creating: [Fluid responsive email newsletter](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/create-fluid-responsive-html-email-newsletter).
Hope this helps many people out there.

Thanks!

Sumesh M.S